# Get titles of all custom post types in a page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm outputting a bunch of custom post types within a page. How do I get all the titles of the posts within this current page?

Comment: Have you designated a separate field for their titles? If not, you should be able to use the native: the_title(). Did you enable the title attribute when you created the custom post type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look at WP_Query() for outputting custom post types. The code below gets all of your custom posts of the type 'custom_post_type', puts them in a variable called $loop and iterates through it, outputting the title of each post contained within.

```
<?php
// Get the 'Profiles' post type
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);

while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();

the_title();

endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

There are other arguments that you can pass in to WP_Query() to make it more suitable for your needs. Documentation can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Answer (score 1):

Right before 'The Loop', you might as well just use:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=your_custom_post_type');?>
```